# Codeigniter, Activerecord and MySQL UDFs

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, user-defined-functions

We're currently using [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) UDFs for regex pattern matching with Codeigniter and Activerecord.  Using the `PREG_REPLACE` UDF, I was able to strip all non numeric and alphabetic characters with a custom query, Activerecord failed and returned an error `result() on a non object`

Works:

```
$query = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE PREG_REPLACE('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/' , '', UPPER(first_name)) = '%s' AND PREG_REPLACE('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/' , '', UPPER(last_name)) = '%s'", $first_name, $last_name));
```

Doesn't work:

```
$this->db->where("PREG_REPLACE('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/' , '', UPPER(first_name))", $first_name);
$this->db->where("PREG_REPLACE('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/' , '', UPPER(last_name))", $last_name);

$query = $this->db->get('table');
```

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it's better to write your own clauses manually as string.

By the way, you could Add a third parameter to the [`where()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) method and set it to `FALSE` to prevent CodeIgniter from protecting your *field* or *table* names with backticks:

```php
$this->db->where("PREG_REPLACE('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/' , '', UPPER(first_name)) = '$first_name'", NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->where("PREG_REPLACE('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/' , '', UPPER(last_name)) = '$last_name'", NULL, FALSE);

$query = $this->db->get('table');
```